# Python + OpenWeatherMap + Flet: 'daily' error

Tags: python, datetime, python-requests, openweathermap, flet

I tried to make my small weather app, following the tutorial, but faced with a problem: OpenWeatherMap wouldn't give me a name of the day (watch the tutorial from my timecode to see my wanted result).

The tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OEyYTdEah4&t=2921s (timecode 56:35)

Parts of my code:

The main one

```
    def _bot_data():
        _bot_data = []
        #range is a number of days for forecast => limited by the API key
        for index in range(1, 8):
            _bot_data.append(
                Row(
                    spacing=5,
                    alignment="spaceBetween",
                    controls=[
                        Row(
                            expand=1,
                            alignment="start",
                            controls=[
                                Container(
                                    alignment=alignment.center,
                                    content=Text(
                                        #week day display
                                        datetime.datetime.weekday(
                                            datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
                                                response['daily'][index]['dt']
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            ]
                        )
                    ]
                )
            )
        return _bot_data


    def _bottom():
        _bot_column = Column(
            alignment="center",
            horizontal_alignment="center",
            spacing=25,
        )

        for data in _bot_data():
            _bot_column.controls.append(data)


        bottom = Container(
            padding=padding.only(top=280, left=20, right=20, bottom=20),
            content=_bot_column
        )
        return bottom`
```

The requests part

```
API_KEY = "my API key"
BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
CITY = "Minsk"
COUNTRY = "BY"
days_en = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
days = days_en

url = BASE_URL + "appid=" + API_KEY + "&q=" + CITY
response = requests.get(url).json()
```

My libraries

```
import datetime
import flet as ft
from flet import *
import requests
import datetime as dt
import math
```

And the error, what I have got:

```
  File "C:\Users\bande\Documents\PycharmProjects\weather_app\main.py", line 290, in _bot_data
    response['daily'][index]['dt']
    ~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'daily'
```

My main question is: how to fix my code (or just a request) to get days names from OpenWeatherMap (for example: today is Saturday and I wanna get the next list - Saturday, Sunday, Monday and etc.). Exactly from OpenWeatherMap, not from datetime library.

When I tried to change the request to `responce['dt']`, I have got days what I need, but in the list of days each day was repeated a large number of times. I'm upset and tired :(

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: thanks, chickity china, I removed my key

Comment: My main question is: how to fix my code (or just a request) to get a day data from OpenWeatherMap (for example: today is Saturday and I wanna get the next list - Saturday, Sunday, Monday and etc.). Exactly from OpenWeatherMap, not from datetime library.

Comment: your code works for me, seems the indexing (`response['daily'][index]['dt']`) is perhaps the only issue, try printing and inspecting the full value of `response`, i.e. `print(response)` and check the available keys. `response['dt']` should return a value.

Comment: Gimme a minute. Just turned of the laptop and wanted to go sleep, hah

Comment: Yup, response['dt'] returns a value

Comment: good progress, try inspecting all available keys, values in `print(response)` and adjust your code to get your desired result

Comment: Just response:
{'coord': {'lon': 27.5667, 'lat': 53.9}, 'weather': [{'id': 804, 'main': 'Clouds', 'description': 'overcast clouds', 'icon': '04n'}], 'base': 'stations', 'main': {'temp': 267.01, 'feels_like': 260.23, 'temp_min': 267.01, 'temp_max': 267.01, 'pressure': 1011, 'humidity': 91, 'sea_level': 1011, 'grnd_level': 984}, 'visibility': 7448, 'wind': {'speed': 5.48, 'deg': 264, 'gust': 11.35}, 'clouds': {'all': 99}, 'dt': 1704496283, 'sys': {'type': 1, 'id': 8939, 'country': 'BY', 'sunrise': 1704522402, 'sunset': 1704549804}, 'timezone': 10800, 'id': 625144, 'name': 'Minsk', 'cod': 200}

Comment: When i typed: print(response['daily']), I got: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bande\Documents\PycharmProjects\weather_app\main.py", line 336, in <module>
    print(response['daily'])
          ~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'daily'

Comment: Seems like OpenWeatherAPI doen't know what 'daily' is, but in the tutorial that guy had no problems with it.

Comment: there is a `daily` field available in the API, https://openweathermap.org/forecast16#name16 example call `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&cnt={cnt}&appid={API key}`

Comment: Here's an example 5 daily forcast using the api_key from the tutorial video: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=53.9&lon=27.5667&appid=30d4741c779ba94c470ca1f63045390a

Comment: you can use a similar query and iterate over the days

Comment: take a break, get some rest, and come back when you get stuck 

Comment: Tried using a few requests like there: openweathermap.org/forecast16#name16
No one helped me. The same error. Argh

Comment: Thanks for your help. Tomorrow I'll try to fix with a help of your video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to the problem. OpenWeatnerMap has several API calls forms. I requested using the name of the city, but to get a forecast for several days you need to request using latitude and longitude (another API call form).

The solution should looks like this:
Requesting latitude and longitude through the name of the city, and then write this data into variables and paste it into another API request form. Voila.

Example of API call:

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=33.44&lon=-94.04&exclude=hourly,daily&appid={API key}
```

The source:
https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api